# how to debug "factor has new levels" error for linear model and prediction

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, prediction, lm

I am trying to make and test a linear model as follows:

```
lm_model <- lm(Purchase ~., data = train)
lm_prediction <- predict(lm_model, test)
```

This results in the following error, stating that the `Product_Category_1` column has values that exist in the `test` data frame but not the `train` data frame):

> factor Product_Category_1 has new levels 7, 9, 14, 16, 17, 18

However, if I check these they definitely look to appear in both data frames:

```
> nrow(subset(train, Product_Category_1 == "7"))
[1] 2923
> nrow(subset(test, Product_Category_1 == "7"))
[1] 745
> nrow(subset(train, Product_Category_1 == "9"))
[1] 312
> nrow(subset(test, Product_Category_1 == "9"))
[1] 92
```

Also showing the table for `train` and `test` show they have the same factors:

```
> table(train$Product_Category_1)

     1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12     13     14     15     16     17     18 
110820  18818  15820   9265 118955  16159   2923  89511    312   4030  19113   3108   4407   1201   4991   7730    467   2430 
> table(test$Product_Category_1)

    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18 
27533  4681  4029  2301 29637  4005   745 22621    92  1002  4847   767  1033   299  1212  1967   100   645 
>
```

Comment: What do `table(train$Product_Category_1)` and  `table(test$Product_Category_1)` tell you? There is not much we can do to help without a reproducible example here.

Comment: `table(train$Product_Category_1)` and `table(test$Product_Category_1)` show they have the same factors (edited the post)

Comment: still need a reproducible example.  Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: One possibility are `NA` values in other variables. `lm` applies `na.omit` and thereby could remove all observations of a specific factor level.

Answer (score 31):

Table of Contents:

- A simple example for walkthrough
- Suggestion for users
- Helpful information that we can get from the fitted model object
- OK, I see what the problem is now, but how to make `predict` work?
- Is there a better way to avoid such problem at all?

---

**A simple example for walkthrough**

Here is simple enough reproducible example to hint you what has happened.

```
train <- data.frame(y = runif(4), x = c(runif(3), NA), f = factor(letters[1:4]))
test <- data.frame(y = runif(4), x = runif(4), f = factor(letters[1:4]))
fit <- lm(y ~ x + f, data = train)
predict(fit, newdata = test)
#Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
#  factor f has new levels d
```

I am fitting a model with more parameters than data so the model is rank-deficient (to be explained in the end). However, this does not affect how `lm` and `predict` work.

If you just check `table(train$f)` and `table(test$f)` it is not useful as the problem is not caused by variable `f` but by `NA` in `x`. `lm` and `glm` drop incomplete cases, i.e., rows with at least one `NA` (see ?`complete.cases`) for model fitting. They have to do so as otherwise the underlying FORTRAN routine for QR factorization would fail because it can not handle `NA`. If you check the documentation at `?lm` you will see this function has an argument `na.action` which defaults to `na.omit`. You can also set it to `na.exclude` but `na.pass` which retains `NA` will cause FORTRAN error:

```
fit <- lm(y ~ x + f, data = train, na.action = na.pass)
#Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
#  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

Let's remove `NA` from the training dataset.

```
train <- na.omit(train)
train$f
#[1] a b c
#Levels: a b c d
```

`f` now has an unused level `"d"`. `lm` and `glm` will drop unused levels when building the model frame (and later the model matrix):

```
## source code of lm; don't run
mf$drop.unused.levels <- TRUE
mf[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)
mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())
```

This is not user controllable. The reason is that if an unused level is included, it will generate a column of zeros in the model matrix.

```
mf <- model.frame(y ~ x + f, data = train, drop.unused.levels = FALSE)
model.matrix(y ~ x + f, data = mf)
#  (Intercept)          x fb fc fd
#1           1 0.90021178  0  0  0
#2           1 0.10188534  1  0  0
#3           1 0.05881954  0  1  0
#attr(,"assign")
#[1] 0 1 2 2 2
#attr(,"contrasts")
#attr(,"contrasts")$f
#[1] "contr.treatment"
```

This is undesired as it produces `NA` coefficient for dummy variable `fd`. By `drop.unused.levels = TRUE` as forced by `lm` and `glm`:

```
mf <- model.frame(y ~ x + f, data = train, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
model.matrix(y ~ x + f, data = mf)    
#  (Intercept)          x fb fc
#1           1 0.90021178  0  0
#2           1 0.10188534  1  0
#3           1 0.05881954  0  1
#attr(,"assign")
#[1] 0 1 2 2
#attr(,"contrasts")
#attr(,"contrasts")$f
#[1] "contr.treatment"
```

The `fd` is gone, and

```
mf$f
#[1] a b c
#Levels: a b c
```

The now non-existing `"d"` level will cause the "new factor level" error in `predict`.

---

**Suggestion for users**

It is highly recommended that all users do the following manually when fitting models:

- **[No. 1]** remove incomplete cases;
- **[No. 2]** drop unused factor levels.

This is exactly the procedure as recommended here: [How to debug "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44200195/4891738) This gets users aware of what `lm` and `glm` do under the hood, and makes their debugging life much easier.

Note, there should be another recommendation in the list:

- **[No. 0]** do subsetting yourself

Users may occasionally use `subset` argument. But there is a potential pitfall: not all factor levels might appear in the subsetted dataset, thus you may get "new factor levels" when using `predict` later.

The above advice is particularly important when you write functions wrapping `lm` or `glm`. You want your functions to be robust. Ask your function to return an informative error rather than waiting for `lm` and `glm` to complain.

---

**Helpful information that we can get from the fitted model object**

`lm` and `glm` return an `xlevels` value in the fitted object. It contains the factor levels **actually** used for model fitting.

```
fit$xlevels
#$f
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

So in case you have not followed the recommendations listed above and have got into trouble with factor levels, this `xlevels` should be the first thing to inspect.

If you want to use something like `table` to count how many cases there are for each factor levels, here is a way: [Get number of data in each factor level (as well as interaction) from a fitted lm or glm [R]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51408919/4891738), although making a model matrix can use much RAM.

---

**OK, I see what the problem is now, but how to make `predict` work?**

If you can not choose to work with a different set of `train` and `test` dataset (see the next section), you need to set those factor levels in the `test` but not in `xlevels` to `NA`. Then `predict` will just predict `NA` for such incomplete cases.

---

**Is there a better way to avoid such problem at all?**

People split data into `train` and `test` as they want to do cross-validation. The first step is to apply `na.omit` on your full dataset to get rid of `NA` noise. Then we could do a random partitioning on what is left, but this this naive way may end up with

- some factor levels in `test` but not in `train` *(oops, we get "new factor level" error when using `predict`)*;
- some factor variables in `train` only have 1 level after unused levels removed *(oops, we get "contrasts" error when using `lm` and `glm`)*;

So, it is highly recommended that you do some more sophisticated partitioning like stratified sampling.

There is in fact another hazard, but not causing programming errors:

- the model matrix for `train` is rank-deficient *(oops, we get a "prediction for rank-deficient model may be misleading" warning when using `predict`)*.

Regarding the rank-deficiency in model fitting, see [lme4::lmer reports "fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient", do I need a fix and how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37090722/4891738) Rank-deficiency does not cause problem for model estimation and checking, but can be a hazard for prediction: [R `lm`, Could anyone give me an example of the misleading case on “prediction from a rank-deficient”?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242540/r-lm-could-anyone-give-me-an-example-of-the-misleading-case-on-prediction-fr/356083#356083) However, such issue is more difficult to avoid, particularly if you have many factors and possibly with interaction.

Comment: Or filling NA's in the training dataset with multiple imputation might be a different way to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Examples of poor binning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znvJC.png)

It's a little unclear what your data looks like, you should use plots of your predictors to get a better idea of what you are dealing with. Here is an example of how deficiency can be an issues in general.

When you cut count data into factors, you need to ensure that you don't have degenerate classes. I.e. there are not zero, or near zero-presentations of that class. Use a bar plot on your class levels. You will note in the image that several classes are problematic in how this data set is splitting into dummy classes. If this was how the data was collected, then you are stuck with missing data, you can try using K-nearest Neighbors imputations, but if too much data is missing then you likely have to recollect the data if it research data (redo the experiment, re-observe the process, etc). If the data is not reproducible, you will need to remove that predictor and annotate your finding to inform your audience.

Comment: Welcome to SO Thomas J Childers ! Your plot seems nice and relevant, it would be better to answer with the code used and include the plot in your answer. You can do so using the `reprex` packages.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/08/data-splitting/

> The function createDataPartition of the caret package can be used to create balanced splits of the data or random stratified split