# How to get around error "factor has new levels" in cross-validation glm?

Tags: r

My goal is to use cross-validation to evaluate the performance of a linear model.

My problem is that my training and testing sets might not always have the same variable levels.

Here is a reproducible data example:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(n = 1000)
y <- rep(x = c("A","B"), times = c(500,500))
z <- rep(x = c("D","E","F"), times = c(997,2,1))

data <- data.frame(x,y,z)

summary(data)
```

Now let's make a glm model:

```
model_glm <- glm(x~., data = data)
```

And let's use cross-validation on this model:

```
library(boot)
cross_validation_glm <- cv.glm(data = data, glmfit = model_glm, K = 10)
```

And this is the kind of error output that you will get:

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor z has new levels F
```

if you don't get this error, re-run the cross validation and at some point you will get a similar error.

The nature of the problem here is that when you do cross-validation, the train and test subsets might not have the exact same variable levels. Here our variable `z` has three levels (`D`,`E`,`F`).

In the total amount of our data there is much more `D`'s than `E`'s and `F`'s.

Thus whenever you take a small subset of the whole data (to do cross-validation).

There is a very good chance that your `z` variable are all going to be set at the `D`'s level.

Thus `E`and `F` levels gets dropped, thus we get the error (This answer is helpful to understand the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51555998/10972294).

My question is: how to avoid the drop in the first place?

If it is not possible, what are the alternatives?

(Keep in mind that this a reproducible example, the actual data I am using has many variables like `z`, I would like to avoid deleting them.)

Comment: Instead of performing a random sample of your initial data set, you could try a stratified sampling approach.  Split your initial set down by your x variable and then randomly sample each subset and then combine the random subsets into your training dataset.

Comment: @DaveT Do you know if there is an available function to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in the comment, I don't know if there is a function or not.  Most likely there is one, but I have no idea on which package would contain it.  For this example, this function should work:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(n = 1000)
y <- rep(x = c("A","B"), times = c(500,500))
z <- rep(x = c("D","E","F"), times = c(997,2,1))
data <- data.frame(x,y,z)

#optional tag row for later identification: 
#data$rowid<-1:nrow(data)

stratified <- function(df, column, percent){
  #split dataframe into groups based on column
  listdf<-split(df, df[[column]])
  testsubgroups<-lapply(listdf, function(x){
    #pick the number of samples per group, round up.
    numsamples <- ceiling(percent*nrow(x))
    #selects the rows
    whichones <-sample(1:nrow(x), numsamples, replace = FALSE)
    testsubgroup <-x[whichones,] 
  })  
  #combine the subgroups into one data frame
  testgroup<-do.call(rbind, testsubgroups)
  testgroup
}

testgroup<-stratified(data, "z", 0.8)
```

This will just split the initial data by column z, if you are interested is grouping by multiple columns then this could be extended by using the `group_by` function from the dplyr package, but that would be another question.

Comment on the statistics: If you just have a few examples for any particular factor, what type of fit do you expect?  A poor fit with wide confidence limits.