# why i'm getting this error "factor has new levels" error while running prediction code for linear regression?

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression

```
s=sample(1:nrow(data), 0.80*nrow(data))

train <- data[s,]
test <- data[-s,]
test1 <- test[!colnames(test) %in% "Sale_Price"]
model1 <- lm(Sale_Price~., data = train)
pred1 <- predict(model1,test1)
```

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action,
> xlev = object$xlevels) :
> factor Condition2 has new levels PosA
> >

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  In partocular we need to see your input data in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552203/how-to-debug-factor-has-new-levels-error-for-linear-model-and-prediction